# How exactly does the Stagefright Vulnerability work on Android?

Tags: android, stagefright

Digital Trends describes the [Stagefright Vulnerability](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/android-stagefright-mms-hack-news/) thus:

> The exploit in question happens when a hacker sends a MMS message containing a video that includes malware code. What’s most alarming about it is that the victim doesn’t even have to open the message or watch the video in order to activate it. The built-in Hangouts app automatically processes videos and pictures from MMS messages in order to have them ready in the phone’s Gallery app.

How is it that a video file that hasn't been 'played' yet can be used to execute malicious code? Would anyone be able to give a more low-level explanation of how this is possible?

P.S.: To protect yourself just make sure to disable all the 'Auto-Download' features for MMS in your messaging apps (Hangout, Messaging, etc.).

Comment: I guess you are right, I was just surprised that this is such a wide-ranging exploit, yet barely anyone knows how it works...

Comment: Certain apps such as Google Hangouts do pre-processing on media before you actually look at it, so that increases the vulnerability

Comment: Here is some information updated 3 days ago -- https://github.com/fuzzing/MFFA

Comment: How the bug being attach in the mp4 file and how do the attacker determine the return address on incoming connection??? Please answer .

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The details will be released on the 5th of august. However, on the Cyanogenmod github repository there are [several interesting details that appear to be related](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/commit/57db9b42418b434751f609ac7e5539367e9f01a6): it appears that certain fields in 3GPP video metadata are vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks. In short, a 3GPP video can be given a string of metadata that, at first, exceeds a certain length, and in the end includes machine code that lands in memory that is off-limits to the application.

Update: Cyanogenmod has released a [patch](https://plus.google.com/+CyanogenMod/posts/7iuX21Tz7n8) for this vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was looking for, let's see what crazy details we will get during Joshua's presentation!

Comment: Very good answer, and thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/commit/4a39c150327e080072d5f8e4239c6bbbbabd48d8) and [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/commit/ebf0d0940f7f42b220b19d3baaee7efb4c6b787d) changes could be relevant.

Comment: It's especially worth noting that the person committing those changes is the person who disclosed the vulns, so it's a fair bet this is it...

Comment: Just curious, isn't fuzz testing performed on Android? If so, how do things like this not get caught?

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah  Good question.  From my experience in systems software QA, though, if you asked it of 100 software testers, one of them would say "Of course not!  Are you nuts?" and the other 99 would say "What's fuzz testing?"

Comment: Now that the 5th of August has been and gone, is there any further information?

Comment: I've tested the exploit  https://github.com/jduck/cve-2015-1538-1/blob/master/Stagefright_CVE-2015-1538-1_Exploit.py and  it didn't work with 5 diff. android versions, only now, the exploit was publicly released, the author states that "**It's only been tested to work on a single device model. My target was the Galaxy Nexus device running Android 4.0.4 containing only a partial implementation of ASLR. Also, due to variances in heap layout, this is not a 100% reliable exploit by itself**, big hype for nothing... BS

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the [commits shown on github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/commits/cm-12.0), Trend Labs have also posted a [more detailed explanation](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/mms-not-the-only-attack-vector-for-stagefright/) of the [integer overflow vulnerability](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_av/commit/5fd0cb515aba32d4dd961c16449bd5c8f4c37a6c) (CVE-2015-3824) on their security blog. They demonstrate how it can be exploited from within an app, from a URL, and using MMS messages.

**Update**: As of 2016, there are now very detailed explanations and exploitations of this vulnerability. Look at the great [Metaphor exploit paper](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/39527) for example.