# Injecting javascript into an alert

Tags: javascript, injection

I have a function like this where `json` is a json object that is in this form
`err`: `someNumber`, and I want to inject javascript into that alert so that maybe i could inject ajax in there or something else, how would I go about doing that?(If it's even possible)

```
function imageShow(json) {
if (json && 'err' in json && json.err != "" && json.err != "200" && json.err != "OK")
    {
        alert (json.err);
    }
}
```

For example:

let `json.err` be `{ "err" : "<script> alert(\"Hey\");</script> }`. and then I could use that alert within the alert.

If not, I have this same function with this
Same json data and same everything, but instead of alerting, it changes a picture's source to the `json.err`:
Could I inject something into this?

```
function imageShow(json) {

if (json && 'err' in json && json.err != "" && json.err != "200" && json.err != "OK")
    {
        $("#img")[0].src = json.err;
    }

}
```

Comment: You write "let `json.err` be `{ "err" : "<script> alert(\"Hey\");</script> }`" - did you mean "let `json.err` be `"<script> alert(\"Hey\");</script>"`"?

Comment: yes that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The message in an `alert()` box is always displayed as plain text. You can't inject code here.
- Setting the `src` of an image to a user-controlled value can't lead to XSS, but some other less severe vulnerabilities as explained [in this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/what-could-an-img-src-xss-do).

Comment: Check my edit, I added another thing I hope I can inject

Comment: @fdsaddsa I amended my answer, but generally please don't extend your question after receiving answers. Instead, you can ask a new question (after checking that it hasn't been asked before).